# Linking Wordpress Subscription to Microsoft Dynamics & Click Dimensions

Tags: wordpress, microsoft-dynamics, hubspot, clickdimension

I would like to move an entire CRM, website, marketing automation settings, blog, landing pages etc. from HubSpot to Microsoft Dynamics & Click Dimensions.

Since Click Dimensions doesn't support much in the way of blogging or landing pages in the same way HubSpot does, I decided to use Wordpress for the blog and landing pages with calls to the ClickDimensions for data capture and processing. This is, for the most part, straightforward.

However, I hit a snag with blog subscriptions. Since blog subscriptions would be handled by Wordpress, is there any easy way to pass the subscribed emails to ClickDimensions from Wordpress, or implement any kind of control on ClickDimensions regarding the emails themselves?

Thanks in advance.